# Sequential JDBC statement executions not transacting

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, transactions

I have the following tables:

```
all_app_users
=============
all_app_user_id         INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
is_enabled              BOOLEAN NOT NULL

myapp_users
===========
myapp_user_id           INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
all_app_user_id         INT FOREIGN KEY (all_app_users)
myapp_user_stage        INT NOT NULL
```

And the following JDBC code:

```
Long allAppUserId = null;
Long myAppId = null;
Connection pooledConn = getPooledDBConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO all_app_users ( is_enabled ) VALUES ( ? )");
    ps.setBoolean(1, true);
    ps.execute();
    ps.close();

    ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('all_app_users')");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    allAppUserId = (long)rs.getInt(0);
    rs.close();

    ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myapp_users ( all_app_user_id, myapp_user_stage ) VALUES( ?, ? )");
    ps.setInt(1, Ints.checkedCast(allAppUserId));
    ps.setInt(2, 5);
    ps.execute();
    ps.close();

    ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('myapp_users')");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    myAppId = (long)rs.getInt(0);

    pooledConn.commit();

    System.out.println("Ping");
} catch(SQLException sqlExc) {
    logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(sqlExc));
    if(pooledConn != null) {
        try {
            pooledConn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
} finally {
    try {
        if(rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }

        if(ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }

        if(pooledConn != null) {
            pooledConn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}

System.out.println("Pong");
```

When I run that code, I don't get any exceptions, and the "Ping" and "Pong" messages print to STDOUT, however `myAppId` is NULL. **I'm wondering why?**

Perhaps it has to do with my use of transactions/commits? Should I be committing after each of the 4 sequential SQL statements? Am I using the JDBC API incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT` does not care about transactions or scope: it returns the last identity key that has been generated for the table.

`IDENT_CURRENT` can return `NULL` when the table has no identity column, never contained rows, or has been truncated. None of this applies in your situation. However, it looks like you are running the scalar query incorrectly: you never call `rs.next()` before calling `rs.getInt(...)`:

```
ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('all_app_users')");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next(); // <<== Add this line
allAppUserId = (long)rs.getInt(0);
rs.close();

ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myapp_users ( all_app_user_id, myapp_user_stage ) VALUES( ?, ? )");
ps.setInt(1, Ints.checkedCast(allAppUserId));
ps.setInt(2, 5);
ps.execute();
ps.close();

ps = pooledConn.prepareStatement("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('myapp_users')");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next(); // <<== Add this line
myAppId = (long)rs.getInt(0);
```

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight (+1) - your answer makes sense, however I get the same result even after adding your `rs.next()` statements. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja That's really odd... You do see a number when you run `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('myapp_users')` in query analyzer, right?

Comment: Yes @dasblinkenlight, this is correct (in SQL Server Management Studio I *do* see valid results). However this is SQL Server, and in a query analyzer I am logging into the server with my AD Windows credentials. In the Java program, I'm using a system/service account. Is it possible that the service account doesn't have read permissions? I would think that would cause a `SqlException` though...

Comment: @IAmYourFaja Yes, that would be another possibility: according to the docs, `IDENT_CURRENT ` "returns `NULL` on error or if a caller does not have permission to view the object." In other words, you wouldn't see `SQLException`, it would be "swallowed" on the SQL Server side.